# Explanation on private variable in c struct

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel

Hi, I was going through the Linux kernel code where I came across the following line in a structure

```
unsigned long private[0] ____cacheline_aligned;
```

It is defined in struct mmc_host. It is used as follows:

```
host = mmc_priv(mmc);

static inline void *mmc_priv(struct mmc_host *host)
{        
     return (void *)host->private;
}
```

I am unable to find where it is initialized since its not in mmc_alloc_host() function.

Refer following link to code. It is defined as last variable inside struct mmc_host.

http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/mmc/host.h

Comment: It's a zero-element array, which is illegal in ISO C but probably an implementation of the [struct hack](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html) depending on a gcc extension. `____cacheline_aligned` is either a macro or a gcc extension. Code that creates `struct mmc_host` objects presumably can allocate extra space for elements of this array; the member name `private` gives you access to those elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a zero-element array, which is illegal in ISO C but probably an implementation of the [struct hack](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html). It depends on a gcc extension.

`____cacheline_aligned` is either a macro or a gcc extension.

Code that creates struct mmc_host objects presumably can allocate extra space for elements of this array; the member name `private` gives you access to those elements.

And in fact the `mcc_alloc_host` function takes an extra argument (appropriately called `extra`) that specifies how many additional bytes to allocate; those extra bytes make up the `private` array:

```
struct mmc_host *mmc_alloc_host(int extra, struct device *dev)
{
...
host = kzalloc(sizeof(struct mmc_host) + extra, GFP_KERNEL);
if (!host)
        return NULL;
```

A call to this function might look something like this:

```
struct mmc_host *ptr = mmc_alloc(N * sizeof (unsigned long), some_pointer);
```